# How to avoid memory leakage when using reactiveFileReader() in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I've built R shiny app, where I quite extensively use `reactiveFileReader()` to read saved data from a file. I've noticed that after some time, the server becomes very slow. After some research, I've found the GitHub issue saying that this might be caused by  [memory leak](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2321).

The issue was solved by [using fastmap as a backing store for map class](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/2429).

However, it is not clear for me, how to use fastmap with `reactiveFileReader()`.

Any help on how to use fastmap with reactiveFileReader or any other method on how to avoid memory leakage here would be highly appreciated as I am currently surviving this by cron rebooting server 5 times a day.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is enough to update `shiny` package to version 1.4.0

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2321#issuecomment-542078052